# firebase.database() is not a function?

Tags: firebase, import

HIHI,
I try to import firebase into my project.
At first step,
I import the code as below:

```
import firebase from '@firebase/app';
require('firebase/auth');
require('firebase/storage');
require("firebase/firestore");
require('firebase/functions');
require('firebase/database');
```

[system console.log the info as this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CPYj.png)
I can't find the database function.

and then I try the code as below:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';
import 'firebase/storage';
```

[Beside database, I can't find other things](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Yn4N.png)

Could anyone tell me what happen?
Thanks first.

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, links are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question.

Comment: I am sorry to provide uncomplete code for your reference. My problem context is that I bought a next.js theme from a website and try to  add the firebase function, and then find this initialization problem. Originally,I think it is a easy question, so I provide the result message as the photo. After these days' checking. I think it should be from the structure  of this theme.  The theme core is too huge to provide. Thanks your advice, Jay. Have a nice day.